# Grails controller URL not found

Tags: grails, model-view-controller, gsp, grails-controller

I have the following Grails 2.3.6 app structure (besides the normal/default Grails structure):

```
myapp/
    grails-app/
        controllers/
            com/me/myapp/fizz/
                BuzzController.groovy
        views/
            foo/
                foo.gsp
```

In `BuzzController`:

```
class SomeController {
    def index() {
        // Do a bunch of stuff

        render(
            view: "foo",
            model: foo
        )
    }
}
```

When I run `grails run-app` and open a browser to

```
http://localhost:8080/myapp/buzz
```

Grails serves back my custom 404 Not Found page. **What's going on, and what can I do to fix it?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your controller put your code like below and see what happens.

```
render(
            view: "/foo/foo",
            model: 
        )
```

If your controller name and the view folder are same then you dont need to give /foo/foo. Just writing "foo" should be fine.

PS. I have not tried this now, but it should work.